# how to rander .html file using cakephp : CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am working on CakePHP and I have a URL http://admin.example.com/Pages .
How can I create http://admin.example.com/Pages.html ? Is there any solution or component to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CakeBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions) , You can define extensions you want to parse in routes

E.g. Write the code below in `app/Config/routes.php`

```
Router::parseExtensions('html');
```

This will allow you to send .html extenstion in routes(url)

Not create a link

E.g:

```
$this->Html->link('Link title', array(
                    'controller' => 'pages',
                    'action' => 'index',
                    'ext' => 'html'
                ));
```

When you click that link you will get url in browser something like this

http://admin.example.com/pages/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need this? CakePHP is automatically render view files from `View` folder

1. You can create (if its `PagesController` and `index` methond) `index.ctp` in `app/View/Pages` folder and it will be automatically render.
2. You can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) function to read files. Something like this:

   // in controller
   function index() {
      $content = file_get_contents('path/to/file.html');
      echo $content;
      die();
   }